# Entity design when principal entity state is an aggregate of its dependant entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

Let's define `Term` as a principal entity and `Course` as a one to many dependant relationship.

```
public class Term 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; } = new List<Course>();
}

public class Course 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

A common query criteria for our `Term` entity is to check whether all of the courses are finished or not and by that we deem the `Term` as finished or not too, and this implicit state can show itself in a lot of places in our bussiness logic, simple queries to populate view models, etc.

Using ORMs like EntityFramework Core this query can popup in a lot of places.

```
Terms.Where(t=>t.Courses.All(c=>c.EndTime > DateTime.Now))
Terms.Count(t=>t.Courses.All(c=>c.EndTime > DateTime.Now))
```

Other examples of this that come to mind are a product and its current inventory count, posts that only contain unconfirmed comments, etc.

What can we consider as best practice if we are to capture these implicit states and make them directly accessible in our principal entity without the need to rehydrate our dependant entity from the database too?

Some solutions that come to mind:

1. Using a computed column to do a subquery and map it to a property on the principal entity e.g. `Term.IsFinished`
2. Defining a normal property on our entity and use a scheduling solution to update its value on predetermined timestamps which is not acceptable in a lot of cases due to inconsistency in different intervals, or use domain events and react upon them to update the property on the principal entity

Answer (score 1):

Create a view, with the two tables joined and aggregated per principal entity.

Use the view directly in Entity Framework instead of the base table.

---

**For bonus points:**

In SQL Server you can create a clustered index on the view, and it will be automatically maintained for you. Oracle has a similar concept.

In other RDBMSs, you would need to create a separate table, and maintain it yourself with triggers.